# curl command for an xmlrpc command

Tags: python, curl, xml-rpc

so i have an XMLRPC server that has a command called start_apps

normally from python I would run it like this

```
import xmlrpclib
app=xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:6610/app_rpc")

app.start_apps()
```

is there any way to call this method from a curl command?

i'm interested from bash or powershell

Comment: it's just http requests, so... yes.

Comment: could you give me an example how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following command will invoke the start_apps command by posting the XML data to the XMLRPC server:

```
curl -d "<?xml version='1.0'?><methodCall><methodName>start_apps</methodName></methodCall>" http://localhost:6610/app_rpc
```

When invoked on Linux use single quotes for the XML fragment.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks, but for example if I have a param for the app such as start_apps('true') how would that work?

Comment: Yes, then insert <params><param><value><boolean>1</boolean></value></param></params> between the methodName elements.

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_request.htm for more information.